# Adding number icon on top right corner of UIBarButtonItem in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

[image: Button with top right corner icon]

I want to add icon with counter(number) on top right corner of UIBarButtonItem in iphone
How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that's not a `UIBarButton`. It's a `UITabBarItem`.

If you want to do that on a `UIBarButtonItem`, you're going to need to initialize it with a custom view and do a bunch of messing around.

If you want to do it with a `UITabBarItem`, just do `tabBarItem.badgeValue = 2;`

Comment: Yes. you are right, it is UITabBarItem's badgeValue, but i want to do same for UIBarButtonItem..!!!

Comment: You can create a custom view and have little images for numbers 1-9, I guess. Then choose the right image to show accordingly. Why do you want to show this on a BarButtonItem? I've never seen it in a UI before, so there's probably a good reason apple doesn't let you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the badgeValue property in UITabBarItem: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBarItem